# DB relationships with historical tables review

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams, data-versioning

Idea is simple. User -> Projects -> Sprints -> Tasks, but I need to keep historical versions for them. It will fit to my requirements or there are some changes to be applied? - or different approach.

[image: database_proposal]

Comment: Do you need to keep the information for audit purposes only, or is there some need to query old values as if they were current?

Comment: @bbaird before creating that schema, I thought that I'll need to query old values also, but right now conception has changed and audit purpose only is acceptable.